# Create an hermetic Maven build

Tags: java, maven, offline

I'm preparing a workshop where they may be no Internet connection. Because of that, I'd like to provide every dependency/plugin of the project, so attendees can work on it, completely offline.

I've got a basic Maven project with some dependencies and two plugins.

First, I created an alternate local repository:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=dependencies dependency:go-offline
```

Then, I expected the following command to run fine, but it doesn't! And I some mentioned missing plugins are not available in maven central or within the maven distribution:

```
mvn -o -Dmaven.repo.local=dependencies package
```

This fail with the following error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project XXX: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6 has not been downloaded from it before.

Any idea how to get these missing bits while creating an alternate local repo? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this issue in the [plugin's Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82) this problem is still not resolved.
The best work around so far is to package the project online once, using the custom repository.

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=dependencies dependency:go-offline
```

then

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=dependencies package
```

and finally

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=dependencies -o package
```

If your workshop go farther than deploy, you should check that next goals run fine offline too!

Comment: The second step means the attendee first needs to build online. Thanks for linking the issue, though!

Comment: Depends what you want to do with the local repository. I expect that you want to share the one you build with the go-offline goal? If so, you can share it after running the initial package goal (done before the workshop of course). No additional dependency should be needed.

Comment: Is the first step necessary here? Doesn't `mvn package` already download the dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

can you declare pluginManagement for every plugin that is used by your packaging? That should enable downloading when dependency:go-offline is called.

(in addition, this will improve stability for your build, since you'll be sure that changing Maven version won't change plugins versions)

Can you confirm this works?
(now, I have ideas to improve this, but won't be available before a few months at least...)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to suggest that you need to run:

```
  mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```

Before `go-offline`

Could you try it?

See: https://people.apache.org/~aramirez/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html

Comment: No, based on [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html), The dependency:go-offline mojo goal is exactly the same as calling mvn dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugins.