# How to solve reducing maven download dependencies time when using docker to build a maven project?

Tags: maven, docker

I have built common mavne dependencies as a base docker image, but when I build a project Dockerfile, it still will download dependencies which will take a long time to build.

Comment: Run your own Nexus/Artifactory server to manage and cache dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Combine [go-offline](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) goal of `maven-dependency-plugin`, [maven's offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233328/how-do-i-configure-maven-for-offline-development) with [docker multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

A reference `Dockerfile` could be :

```
# Step : Test and package
FROM maven:3.5.3-jdk-8-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /build
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

COPY src/ /build/src/
# -o flag will instruct maven to build on offline mode
RUN mvn -o package

# Step : Package image
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
EXPOSE 4567
CMD exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app/my-app.jar
COPY --from=builder /build/target/*jar-with-dependencies.jar /app/my-app.jar
```

Invoking `dependency:go-offline` will fetch the required artifacts from the internet to the container's local repository. Thanks to docker layer caching, this step will be cached so it will be skipped in a new build attempt.

An important note is that copying `pom.xml` should precede source code copying as a change on `pom.xml` must trigger a new pull of maven artifacts as project's dependencies may have changed.

[Reference](https://medium.com/@nieldw/caching-maven-dependencies-in-a-docker-build-dca6ca7ad612)

**EDIT:** Note that depending on your `pom.xml`, you may face an [open Maven Dependency plugin issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82) on which some dependencies are not fetched from `go-offline` goal **as they should**, resulting in build failure. As a workaround, you can try [Romain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43230733).

Comment: First ,thanks for your answer.
I have tried your suggestion,I just modified src, not pom.xml,  but when command is running to "RUN mvn dependency:go-offline", build dependencies time is still too long everytime, dependencies cache was not used. Have you found out this issue ?

Comment: @Mr.Cao Sorry for the delay. I have updated my answer, main points of the update are the addition of `-o` flag on `mvn package` command and the info on edit section.

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't docker cache the output of `RUN mvn -o package` instead? This command also downloads the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Using `docker` [experimental features](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md) and [`buildit`](https://github.com/moby/buildkit) you can mount a (shared) cache volume during your builds for example:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM fabric8/maven-builder
...
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.1.43 && \
    mvn clean install ...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. In this way, Docker daemon needs to run in experimental mode. it's not suitable for developing.

Comment: It not being suitable is specific to your use case (e.g. suits us just fine). Can build a dind image with the daemon config baked in and use that as your portable development environment.