# How to build docker image with maven?

Tags: java, maven, docker

I have to build a docker image and package java application using maven in the docker container but when I run the build process all is going fine but all maven dependencies downloading from maven remote repo.

That is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu_img
CMD ./mvnw -s .mvn/settings.xml --batch-mode clean package
```

How can I configure docker or maven for downloading dependencies from maven local repository located on my laptop?

Comment: Or you can package locally and add to container.

Comment: @pmverma no I have to run the maven build in the docker container because all tests have to be executed in the docker environment.

Comment: You can also map local m2 repo to container m2 repo in which case it won't download from remote.

Comment: With `docker` experimental features enabled and using `buildkit` you can mount a cache volume during the builds, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57789560/1423507).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you need to attach the directory of your existing local Maven repository into the Docker container:

`VOLUME ["/home/<user>/.m2", "/root/.m2"]`

Then you need to tell Maven (inside your container) to use this directory as a local repository.

**setting.xml**

```
<settings ...>
    <localRepository>/root/.m2</localRepository>
    ...
</settings>
```

Comment: where I should write ```VOLUME ["/home/<user>/.m2", "/root/.m2"]``` in my docker file?

Comment: You need to add 'VOLUME ...' into the docker-compose.yml file. More info here: http://blog.code4hire.com/2018/06/define-named-volume-with-host-mount-in-the-docker-compose-file/

Comment: More examples are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248198/how-to-mount-a-single-file-in-a-volume

Comment: Can I mount the volume in docker file on build image step without docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: This is a different question. I think that, the best you can do is to complete this question then you can search for it on the Internet or ask a new question.

Comment: Anyway, have you checked this documentation? https://dmp.fabric8.io

Comment: I'm new in docker and I need to solve the issue very quickly but I don't understand what is going on in the dockers. I tried to find a solution but I couldn't. And no I didn't see this documentation.

Comment: I don't understand why no simple solution for this simple issue mount local maven repo on the build stage in docker? I'm very disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

use volume,like this:

`VOLUME ["/home/test/.m2", "/root/.m2"]`